# Linear programming: inequality constraints, constrain domain of weights, constrain # of non-zero weights

Tags: linear-programming

$x$ is a known matrix, $y$ is a known vector, solve for $w$ (weights vector) given the following constraints.

- $w_1 x_{1,1} + w_2 x_{2,1} + \dots + w_n x_{n,1} = y_1$
- $w_1 x_{1,2} + w_2 x_{2,2} + \dots + w_n x_{n,2} \geq y_2$
- $w_1 x_{1,3} + w_2 x_{2,3} + \dots + w_n x_{n,3} \leq y_3$
- ${}\quad\vdots$
- $w_1 x_{1,m} + w_2 x_{2,m} + \dots + w_n x_{n,m} \gt y_m$
- all weights must be positive, upper bounded (e.g. $0 \leq w_i \leq 5)$
- number of non-zero weights should be small relative to $m$ (e.g. 10 non-zero weights when $m$ is 10,000)

I am new to linear programming. How should I go about solving this problem? If applicable, what software packages and functions in those packages should I use?

Comment: What do you want to maximize or minimize ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't have anything to maximize or minimize at the moment. I could add a price to each $x_i$, minimizing the sum cost ($\sum w_i x_{i,price}$), if that helps.

Comment: So, with the price as objective, it looks like my problem is the classic diet problem with the added constraint on the number of non-zero weights (cardinality constraint). Any ideas on solution methods?